# Must i register one application for every pep proxy on Keyrock Idm?

Tags: fiware, fiware-wilma, fiware-keyrock

Guess that we have multiple Fiware Generic Enablers deployed in Docker.

I would like to protect those services with one pep proxy for each one.

Is it ok to register my app and deploy multiple pep proxies with the same credentials give by Idm Keyrock.

Or i must register one app for each microservice and create a different pep proxy with its own credentials?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how do you want to manage AC in the applications. Ideally, you should register each application individually for being able to manage AC policies separately for each one.